# Edit sudoers to allow /sbin/ifconfig down with NOPASSWD

Tags: linux, unix, sudo, sudoers

I'm trying to edit /etc/sudoers so that I can execute a bash script with a root password.

so far every edit I've tried to sudoers is not working.

I've tried adding each of these lines:

```
%admin    ALL= NOPASSWD: /sbin/ifconfig

%admin    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/ifconfig

%users    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/ifconfig

"myusername"  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/ifconfig
```

Each time I am able to save and quit out of visudo without any warning about syntax errors. 
But then when I try to execute the ifconfig command from my admin account, it still says 'permission denied'

```
ifconfig en0 down
ifconfig: down: permission denied
```

Can someone please tell me what is going wrong? 
thanx

Answer (score 3):

You have to prefix your command submission with 'sudo'.  In your case, the command would be:

```
 sudo ifconfig en0 down
```

Also, with your config you are allowing ANY `ifconfig` command line parameters to be used.  The correct and much more restrictive sudoers entry is:

```
 %admin     ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/ifconfig en0 down
```

Please do read the `man` pages on sudo and look at the various good sources of `sudo` information out there via google.